# Console colored output works with NodeJS but not with PHP. Why?

Tags: php, node.js, cmd

I cannot find solution and explanation of this problem. I have this simple program for NodeJS:

```
var colored = ' \u001b[1;41mFAILED\u001b[0m';
console.log(colored);
```

And on Win8 it prints colored output into the CMD. **But**... If I write very similar program in PHP:

```
$color = "[1;41mFAILED\x1b[0m";
print chr(27) . $color;
```

It doesn't work. The output is `←[1;41mFAILED←[0m`. But why? Why it works only with NodeJS? **Where is the difference?** <strike>And how can I print colored output in PHP?</strike> It's obvious that it's possible if NodeJS can do this without additional programs needed. Thanks...

Comment: Do you really think, that there is explanation of my NodeJS question or solution of this problem **without** any additional program?

Comment: nodejs make terminal support ansi. php not do it. cmd.exe not support ansi.

Comment: Ok, but I am using the same CMD for running NodeJS and PHP. So back to the question. How does it do NodeJS internally? I want to do the same in PHP if possible (without DLLs as suggested before). The goal is to make this possible for every user without additional installation of something...

Comment: nodejs support native windows cmd colors and translate ansi to it. php don't support it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16799175/1347147

Comment: Are you kidding me? How this can be duplicate question? Hope the last edit clarify what's the main question...

Comment: For NodeJS you can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25107254/1710825