# How to run a script when starting the Node.js console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to configure the Node.js console window (node.exe) to run a script on startup?

I'd like to do some minor initialization automatically each time, such as setting variables and [colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20344886/634824).

It's not sufficient to just run `node.exe myinitscript.js`. That will run the script and then exit.

I'd like to run the script, and then *remain* in in the console environment.

Comment: Making a npm module which sets colors like https://www.npmjs.com/package/color-util-logs#readme and require it is the best way i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to create your own script that starts the `repl` instead. Create a script with:

```
global.something = 'blah';

require('repl').start({});
```

That will do some init and create some globals or whatever, and then run the repl, just like if you ran `node.exe` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `start` or the `predeploy` property of the `scripts` object of your `package.json`.

The `start` property: The start-up script for the package. When running `npm start` this script will be called.

The `predeploy` property: The pre-deploy script for this application. This script will run before a snapshot of your package has been created. It can therefore be used to compile and optimize assets before it's upload to your application.

For your reference, here's a cheatsheet for the general syntax/structure of the package.json file.

http://browsenpm.org/package.json

Comment: I'm just running node.exe.  I'm not creating a package or running npm.  Is there a general place to put an npm package that will always get executed when node.exe runs?