# Webpack watch output formatting

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Right now I have a webpack so that it watches my code base and recompiles when it detects a change. I didnt like the output on cmd so I added a function in the the plugins array in the webpack.config. That function console logs the compile number and the time at which the compilation finished. I was wondering if anyone knew how to change the color of the cmd output just to make it that much easier to make sure my code has been compiled.

heres what the output looks like so far with the names obscured. I was trying to get those first two lines to be a different color so that they stand out more.

[image]

Comment: Would this be of any help http://stackoverflow.com/a/27111061/1339516 ? Since you say use `console.log()` to terminal in your plugin

Comment: i actually found a way to do it using cli-colors, thank you though!
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-color