# Is there a way to color console.log messages in WebStorm like dev tools?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Is there a way to color console.log messages in WebStorm like dev tools?

see image

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You could do something like:

```
console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'I am cyan');  //cyan
```

`%s` is where in the string gets injected.

**Colors reference**

```
Reset = "\x1b[0m"
Bright = "\x1b[1m"
Dim = "\x1b[2m"
Underscore = "\x1b[4m"
Blink = "\x1b[5m"
Reverse = "\x1b[7m"
Hidden = "\x1b[8m"

FgBlack = "\x1b[30m"
FgRed = "\x1b[31m"
FgGreen = "\x1b[32m"
FgYellow = "\x1b[33m"
FgBlue = "\x1b[34m"
FgMagenta = "\x1b[35m"
FgCyan = "\x1b[36m"
FgWhite = "\x1b[37m"

BgBlack = "\x1b[40m"
BgRed = "\x1b[41m"
BgGreen = "\x1b[42m"
BgYellow = "\x1b[43m"
BgBlue = "\x1b[44m"
BgMagenta = "\x1b[45m"
BgCyan = "\x1b[46m"
BgWhite = "\x1b[47m"
```

Details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407246/2589276

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible; styling console output is not supported. Please vote for [WEB-12349](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12349) to be notified on any progress

Answer (score 1):

worked for me like this:

```
var red = ['color: red'].join(';');
```

and to output:

```
console.log("%c I'm RED!",red)
```

EDIT: Works for me only in Chrome and Firefox