# npm nodemon & npm colors - colors not working with nodemon

Tags: node.js, npm, git-bash, nodemon

Does anyone know how to run 'nodemon' to be displaying console colors using npm 'colors' package ? is it possible ?

Only today I found out about the existence of 'colors' package that allows to log out colorful strings into console, which make things a lot more readable to me. Unfortunately, when I run my app using nodemon, colors not working. When I run my app simply using node, then colors are working properly.

- colors version 1.1.2
- nodemon version 1.11
- git version 2.8.1.windows.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try running `nodemon` without its own colors: `nodemon --no-colors test.js`. I tested it out on a Mac and had no issues. (Sorry, I don't have a Windows box to test on.)

Not necessarily a solution to the actual problem you're facing but it's probably best to use a module that is still updated like [chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk).

Comment: Didn't find a solution. Tried chalk as you recommended, and will stick with that for now. thx!

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a solution to the OP but if someone wants a **coloured output on console for better readability**: ( solution i wanted to implement )
you can do something like:

```
const color = '\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m';
console.log(color, 'some console content');
```

It works with nodemon and pm2 (tested: git windows )
Ref: [How to change node.js's console font color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781218/how-to-change-node-jss-console-font-color?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)