# Change font size in tty / console / terminal

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I have some console output (on Jenkins) and the table results get mangled because they are too wide. These tables are written to the console, each with a single console.log() call, because the tables are just formatted strings with newline and tab characters, that's all.

Here is a visual of the problem:

[image]

When writing this table to the console, is there a way to temporarily change the font size?

Something like:

```
require('tty').fontSize(5);
console.log(myTableString);
require('tty').fontSize(10);
```

something like that?

Comment: Font size is an attribute of the terminal, not the program output.

Comment: You can not change a font size, but you can change a [font colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781218/how-to-change-node-jss-console-font-color).

Comment: elithrar - right, so that's why I think it might be require('tty') which could modify the current TTY

Comment: Don't you just want to change the CSS property? You're talking about Jenkins, where is [tag:node.js] there?

Comment: node.js process is what is responsible to writing to stdout/stderr here

Comment: there is no CSS here, this is not a web browser, just terminal stuff

Comment: okay, then I don't get the "I have some console output (on Jenkins)"

Comment: Jenkins is a webserver that runs jobs and displays the logs of each job - the display is fine, but it will wrap text if it's too long, just like a terminal window. Therefore if I wrote smaller text to the terminal, it should work.