# Is there a way to just highlight specific words in node.js console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

I'd like to get a very special console output for my node.js console...

I'd like to highlight just specific words e.g. ('ERROR', 'SUCCESS', ...) in specific colors (red,green,...).

Is there an easy way to achieve this or do I have to check the console output every time & test if the output includes my word ('error') to laterone color it??

BTW thats how I've catched the console output:

```
console.log = function(d) {
  process.stdout.write(d + '\n'); 
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781218/how-to-change-node-jss-console-font-color

Comment: Depends on what the terminal you're using with node supports…