# Set output color in javascript

Tags: javascript, console, compatibility

I saw this code in other question , and i know that it works in chrome console, but this not work in javascript console, like jsbin or stackoverflow snippet.

**How can i make it work in all console, with compatibility?**

```js
console.log('%c Oh my heavens! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
```

Comment: You probably can't, what do you need it for? You can use `console.warn` and `console.error` to differentiate your outputs

Comment: You can look at this question, I think it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781218/how-to-change-node-jss-console-font-color

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because features provided by console in JSBin or Stackoverflow snippets are a subset of those available in the browser.

Comment: wow, the unknowledge is for close questions, It would be a crime to have questions!

Comment: stackoverflow snippets does support *some* placeholders like %i, %s, %o, but they don't support colors, so no %c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't. They need to implement it first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple implementation without "%" syntax (I just want to show you that you don't really need this feature) :

```js
var styles = "background:#222;color:#bada55";
log("you could do", style(styles, "this"));
log("you could do", style(styles, "this"));
log("you could do", style(styles, "this"));
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
<style>div{border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;padding:.5em}</style>
<script>!function(pre){this.log=function(){var a=document.createElement("div");a.innerHTML=Array.prototype.join.call(arguments," ");pre.appendChild(a)};this.style=function(a,b){return'<span style="'+a+'">'+b+"</span>"};}(document.getElementById("pre"));</script>
```