# style links in javascript console

Tags: javascript, colors, hyperlink, console, styling

i have a console.log message on my site with a link.
The styling is working but the link remains in black font on white background.
Can i change that?

```
$(function() {
  var t = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  if (/(chrome|firefox|safari)/.test(t.toLowerCase())) {
    var e = ["padding: 20px 5px 16px", "background-color: #171718", "color: #f2641c"].join(";");
    var i = ["padding: 20px 5px 16px", "background-color: #f2641c", "color: #ffffff"].join(";"),
        n = ["background-color: transparent"].join(";");
    console.log("\n\n %c Some text %c http://google.com/ %c \n\n\n", e, i, n);
  } else {
    window.console && console.log("Some text - http://google.com/");
  }
});
```

[image: console output]

Comment: Seems like the fact that your text is considered as a link is preventing your styling to be applied. If you add a space after `http:`, you'll see your color, but you'll lose the link.

Comment: @Zenoo so i guess theres no way to change the color and keep the link? :/

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781218/how-to-change-node-jss-console-font-color

Comment: @constantin-chirila doesn't work with links either.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to color links within console messages in Chrome.

If you try to apply a color, Chrome will apply their anchor color anyway:

[image]

Firefox will use the color but force `font-style: italic` (you can't override this behavior):

[image]

Safari will use a gray color:

[image]

All these browsers force `text-decoration: underline` on links in the console.

Side note: I [wrote about](https://frontendmasters.com/blog/console-delight/) how you can include a lot more than just text inside of consoles, which might help people viewing this thread later.

I'd love to see browsers improve support and standardize things here.