# Incorrect display of text in the console

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Color does not work for links in the console, how can this be fixed?
The first two lines are displayed fine, but the third line is not working correctly:

[image: console output]

```
console.log('%cHello-hello-hello', 'color: #5865f2; font: 700 68px sans-serif;-webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;');
console.log('%cat the link below', 'color: #5865f2; font: 700 24px sans-serif;');
console.log('%chttps://stackoverflow.com/', 'color: #000; font: 700 18px sans-serif;');
```

Comment: A quite similar question has been asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728760/style-links-in-javascript-console

Comment: `console.log('%c https://'+'%cstackoverflow.com/', "color: #5865f2; font: 700 18px sans-serif;", "color: #5865f2; font: 700 18px sans-serif;");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately if the string is a full URL there's some default behaviour you can't override the solution Is to only pass the hostname without the HTTP protocol and manually append the protocol as a string before the hostname.

This should work

```
const css = "color: #000; font: 700 18px sans-serif;"
console.log('%c https://'+'%cstackoverflow.com/', css, css);
```

[image]

Comment: `'%c https://'+'%cstackoverflow.com/'` will work too

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Odd when I tried it didn't work seems to be working now anyway thanks for the feedback I have updated the answer.

Comment: then it only display text but not working as Link

Answer (score 0):

Check applied color its black.
Try this i have applied other color in link and it's working fine

```
console.log('%chttps://stackoverflow.com/', 'color: #5865f2; font: 700 18px sans-serif;');
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine in firefox, but not in google chrome

Comment: @Hooxy oke understood

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be by design as pointed out in this comment:

> // Make sure that allowed properties do not interfere with link visibility.

https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/ef157dab2ccf321941548a51d350f9383a78d283/front_end/panels/console/ConsoleViewMessage.ts#L928

This makes sense so links cannot be hidden in the console.