# Is it possible to console.log in RGB using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, colors, terminal, console.log

For my project I need to be able to print to the NodeJS console in RGB. In most browser I can use `console.log('%c Oh my heavens! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');` but that doesn't work in NodeJS.

I have looked at the [colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors) module but that doesn't seem to support custom colors.

It is possible to achieve this?

Comment: yes ... i get that with log4js and a forever wrapper.

Comment: info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781218/how-to-change-node-jss-console-font-color

Answer (score 2):

NodeJS console not work this way. You can use terminal colors like this:

```
console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'I am cyan'); //cyan 
console.log('\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m', stringToMakeYellow); //yellow
```

There is little more about terminal colors: https://askubuntu.com/q/558280

Answer (score 0):

There is a Node module called Tynt- and it brings easy coloring to the Node.js console.

```
var tynt = require("tynt");

console.log(tynt.Blue("Your blue text here!") + "  " + tynt.Red("Your red text here!"))
```

If you want a list of colors, you can find them here:

[github.com/muzzen/tynt](https://github.com/muzzen/tynt#readme.md)

Thanks for reading!