# How to output testcafe console log in green colour?

Tags: console, automated-tests, console.log, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to log some messages while running a test. The messages are logging just fine with the statement console.log but I want to log the messages in green color so I am writing like below but all of it is coming as text rather than green color.

```
console.log(`%c ${process.name} completed`, 'color: green');
```

the output is

```
%c Process1 completed 'color:green'
```

expected output is (in green color)

```
Process1 completed
```

Comment: The solution you are trying (CSS)  is for browser's console. Testcafe is running in Node and output is shown in terminal, so you need to send special characters to terminal to change color: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781218/how-to-change-node-jss-console-font-color

Comment: Thanks that did it.

Comment: For some reason Dim doesn't work as per the example given in the link. do you know why?

Comment: This has no relation to TestCafe, it is just Node code. So you can use any library that helps you deal with terminal colors. Like this one: https://github.com/Marak/colors.js
Please note, i did not tried any of these myself - just pointing where to look.
There are more packages here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13336745/318097

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use the "[colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors)" Node module. For example:

```
import Colors from 'colors'

test('My test', async t => {
     console.log("Process1 completed".green);      
});
```