# How to chain multiple console outputs with different formatting in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

Thanks to the question [How to change node.js's console font color?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9781218/4818123), I learned how to change the console output's font color natively.

The next step was the applying of the multiple formattings to single string.
The solution like

```js
console.log("\x1b[2m", "\x1b[31m", "\x1b[44m", "Sample Text", "\x1b[0m");
```

sometimes works, sometimes - no, but experimentally I explored that we can just concatenate multiple... what is it called? ANSII command sequence? The escape sequence?

```js
console.log("\x1b[41m\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m", "Formatted output");
```

[image]

Now, how can I join the multiple strings with different formatting? For example, the red background and yellow foreground first, than yellow background? Below experiment gave the output does not match wit desired

```
console.log("\x1b[41m\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m", "Output", "\x1b[43m\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m", "Another formatted output");
```

[image]

Please, no recommendations of third-party libraries here, because current topics is focusing on native solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using substitution strings, but the parameters are

```
console.log(msg [, subst1, ..., substN]);
```

Only the first argument should contain the substitution strings. The other arguments contain the strings that are used to substitute. You can log with

```
console.log("\x1b[41m\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m\x1b[43m\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m", "Output", "Another formatted output");
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) you can find more details about `console.log`.