# Change text color in console

Tags: node.js, colors, console

I want to change the console text color in my node console (command prompt) when using `console.info()` or `console.error()`. I know you can change text color with some backslashes and color codes, but is there a way to make it default some colors? Like `console.error()` could default to red, and `console.warn()` could default to yellow. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could overwrite those `console` functions with your own, [with your desired color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407246/9515207):

```
// Save a reference to the original functions
const { info, error } = console;
console.info = (arg) => {
  info.call(console, `\x1b[33m${arg}\x1b[0m`);
};
console.error = (arg) => {
  info.call(console, `\x1b[31m${arg}\x1b[0m`);
};
```

And so on. Use whatever colors you want.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this is from a node.js console, or command prompt.

Comment: Same thing works, just overwrite the built-in functions with your own. It's not a great idea (overwriting built-ins never is), but it's possible.

Comment: Alrighty, Ill try that, thanks!