# How can I get a specialized log() to accept many arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, console.log

I have been using this logger in node:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781218/how-to-change-node-jss-console-font-color
function logC(text) {
  console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', text);
}
```

However it does not work for multiple arguments.  I want to be able to use it like:

```
logC(text1, text2)
```

Obviously, I could write out the arguments in the function signature but I was hoping there was a way to do it with the built in arguments.

Comment: Are you only logging strings or are you trying to completely replicate the `console.log` interface?

Comment: So just `console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', Array.from(arguments).join(' '));`? Or use rest parameter syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
function logC(...args) {
  args.forEach((arg) => {
    console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', arg);
  })
}
    
logC('a', 'b', 'cccc', 'dsff') // This gives the output
```

Comment: Check the edited code.