# 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'

Tags: javascript, node.js, nvm

I want to get data from the twitter-API-client about the most recent 3 followers.

```
async function get_followers() {
  const followers = await twitterClient.accountsAndUsers
    .followersList({
      count: 3,
    });
 console.log(followers);
}

// call function
get_followers();
```

Packages are installed properly. But it's showing an error

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "#<Object>".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

I am using node v 8.12.1

Comment: You didn't show the most important part of the error. Please post all relevant details, or if you can't find the error message, put the code in a proper try block and log the caught error. The error is very likely because Twitter rejected your request.

Comment: The error is pretty self explaining, isn't it? You are calling a function that raised an exception and you are not catching that exception. Use `try ... catch` and check what the exception is

Comment: And btw your node version is quite outdated and isn't supported anymore for more than two years. You should really consider moving to a more current version ...

Answer (score 0):

With just that error information, these errors can be difficult to trace, so you need better handling of uncaught exceptions.

So, step 1 is this. For some reason, this is often much more revealing than that. I don't understand why similar functionality isn't default baked into node. This is a basic implementation, but you can get more information by catching the promise.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    console.log(reason, promise);
    // Application specific error-handling here
});
```

This is great for unhandled exceptions. This will also prevent these errors from crashing server.

For my server, at startup, certain configurations are checked. If they don't pass, I *want* the server to crash.

So I created a class. There's a few ways to do this, but this worked for me

```
export class ServerCrasher {
    public obj: any;
    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.obj = obj
    }
}
```

When I want an exception to crash the server, I wrap it in ServerCrasher and run code like this.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    promise.catch(async (e: any) => {
        if (e instanceof ServerCrasher) {
            ColorLog(['bgRed', "Server Forcefully Crashed due to uncaught promise exception."])
            ColorLog(['red', e.obj])
            let i = 0;
            try {
                while (i < 200 && serverProcess === undefined) {
                    await asyncDelay(500);
                    i++;
                }
                // serverProcess is my https-server, obviously
                serverProcess?.close(async () => {
                    ColorLog(['gray', 'Server taken offline.']);
                    await asyncDelay(1000)
                    process.exit(0);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                ColorLog(['gray', 'Failed to gracefully take the server offline']);
                ColorLog(['gray', error]);
                process.exit(2);
            }
            return;
        }
        
        // Simple logging of the error, but the server stays online
        ColorLog(['bgRed', reason])
        ColorLog(['red', e])
    })
});
```

Please note that ColorLog is my implementation, based on code by others. You can use whatever logging you prefer, or copy mine (or others') [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77291703/3917091).

And lastly, here's `asyncDelay`

```
export function asyncDelay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```