# Why isn't my Node package being imported?

Tags: node.js, module, azure-functions, chalk

I'm learning Node.js and am using a Node-based [Azure Function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview).

I'm trying to bring in [Chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk), to log coloured messages to the console.

However, all of the below fail (in my main `index.js` file).

#### One

```
module.exports = async (ctx, req) => {
    const chalk = require('chalk');
    return console.log(chalk.blue('Hello world!'));
```

Despite being the approach recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13336745/1352288), this results in a console error that says:

> Exception: require() of ES Module C:...\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js from C:...\index.js not supported.
> Instead change the require of C:...\chalk\source\index.js in C:...\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

#### Two

If I do as the error suggests, and use

```
const chalk = async import('chalk')
```

...I then get

> Exception: chalk.blue is not a function

...even though `console.log(chalk)` does seem to show the Chalk API and its various properties.

#### Three

The Chalk docs themselves [recommend](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) this:

```
module.exports = async (ctx, req) => {
    import chalk from 'chalk'
    return console.log(chalk.blue('Hello world!'));
```

That yields an error saying I can't use `import` outside of a module (but surely I'm in one?)

#### Four

Same as three ^^ but moving the `import` outside `module.exports`:

```
import chalk from 'chalk'
module.exports = async (ctx, req) => {
    return console.log(chalk.blue('Hello world!'));
```

...yields the same error.

I'm sure this is a basic error but I can't find what I'm doing wrong so I'd be so grateful if someone could help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import something using import as a function(lazy import), It'll return an object with a default property and all exported properties. That you should use to access the module.

```
const module = async import('chalk')
const chalk = module.default
console.log(chalk.red('Hello world!'))
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. Interestingly, it logs blue text, though, not red, but that's a separate question. Out of interest, why might an error refuse to be imported via `requre()`, as per the error message in my first attempt, necessitating the use of `import()` instead?

Comment: @user9540234 chalk only supports ES module, not CJS. That is why It does not allow required.